# Connect application to Jira rest api using Windows credentials

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

My application connects to Jira for data extraction. To do that, I used the following code:

```
public string RunQuery(JiraRessource resource, string project_id, int startAt, int maxResults, string method = "GET")
{
    string url = string.Format(m_BaseUrl);
    if (project_id != null)
    {
        string jql = "search?jql=project=" + project_id;
        url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, jql);
    }
    string jqr = "&startAt=" + startAt + "&maxResults=" + maxResults;
    url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, jqr);
    Console.WriteLine(url);
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = method;
    string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
    //string base64Credentials = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token.ToString();
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
    string result = string.Empty;

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
}

private string GetEncodedCredentials()
{
    string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_username, m_password);
    byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
}
```

The user has to enter the username and the password to connect. I want to change that in order to connect directly using windows credentials. I have no idea on how to do that. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

WebRequest class has a Credentials property. You can set it with a new NetworkCredential object. You can also set it to logged in windows user. Sample code;

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain);
```

or

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```